# How to get new variable value from inherited class?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance

```
open class Parent(){
  protected var z : Int? = null

  private fun getMyAge(){
    val x = 65
    val y = 10
    z = x % y 
  }
}

class Child:Parent(){
 ovveride fun getMyAge()
  println(z)  //here I get null
}
```

My question is: why I get null?
Am I getting a variable from an inherited class incorrectly?

Comment: ``z`` in ``Parent`` is initialised as null, and then you never set it (you're not calling ``getMyAge()``, and that just creates a new local variable called ``z`` that's immediately discarded anyway)

Comment: thank you for answer.  I am calling `getMyAge()` in Child class. Sorry, I missed it. But the same, I get null

Comment: No, you still don't call it and you still don't set `z` property, but only `z` local variable. Did you read through the official guide for Kotlin? Because your problems are really about very basic stuff and I guess even if you fix this, you will have a lot of similar problems.

Comment: @broot
 sorry, I am newcomer in Kotlin and I don't understand how to set `z` property, getter() and setter() are default, no?

Comment: `val z =` defines a local variable. You need to use `z =` or optionally `this.z =`. And again, right now you don't really invoke `getMyAge()` anywhere in the provided code. It's hard to make any conclusions about your `Child` class, because this code isn't a valid Kotlin code, it doesn't compile. Also, I'm not entirely sure what do you try to accomplish here, but it is very strange that `getMyAge()`, which sounds like it should return the age, actually doesn't return anything, but instead it sets a property. I apologize for maybe being a little rude, but this code is really confusing :-)

Comment: @broot
 yes, sorry, your are right. I had mistake. I just want get  `z = x % y`. so, in Child class I need get result of `x % y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you override the function, the super function is not called.  If you want the function in parent class called, you must change your code to this:

```
open class Parent(){
  protected var z : Int? = null

  private fun getMyAge(){
    val x = 65
    val y = 10
    z = x % y 
  }
}

class Child:Parent(){
 ovveride fun getMyAge()
  super.getMyAge()
  println(z)
}
```

Comment: oh, your are right! It is my stupid mistake!